# Using php with database in a javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

This code is when i hardcore the sentence "Have a nice day!", it will echo out the exact same line. My question is what if i want to retrieve sentence from the database, instead of hard-coding it.

```
<?php
    $php_var = "Have a nice day!";
?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script>
    var js_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
    //var js_var = "Try123";
    document.writeln(js_var);
   //document.writeln(js_var);
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I am suppose to do something like this is it? but it cant work. It printed out  `"SELECT * FROM sen WHERE id=1 ;"` on the page.

```
<?php
   $con = mysql_connect(localhost,root,password,database_name);
   $php_var = "SELECT * FROM sen WHERE id=1 ;";
?>


    <script>
  var js_var = "<?php echo  $php_var ; ?>";
  //var js_var = "Try123";
 document.writeln(js_var);
 //document.writeln(js_var);
</script>
```

Comment: currently you only assign your query to a variable you're supposed to run it on your connection and then extract the result, im currently looking up how to do this again.

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 4):

You're not executing the query and fetching the result. Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(localhost,root,password,database_name);
$php_var = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sen WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1")); 
?>

<script>
  var js_var = "<?php echo  $php_var['id']; ?>";
  //var js_var = "Try123";
 document.writeln(js_var);
 //document.writeln(js_var);
</script>
```

Please be aware of some things:

- Don't forgot error handling on the right way. (Not or die)
- Check if the MySQL connecton was successfully made.
- Possibility of MySQL injection
- I've updated `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, this because `mysql_*` is deprecated and will being removed in the future.

Comment: change it to mysqli_ ... there's no point on teaching deprecated functions

Comment: Instead of showing someone how not to do it, just show them how it should be done, and add a sidenote about the deprecated functions.

Comment: @Wouter0100  Its giving this two errors- Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: @user3773928 Excuus me, I always use the Object oriented one. I've edited my answer, please try again. :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you create a Rest api with json response backend in PHP and then have a javascript frontend using like JQuery $get or something.

Comment: This answer is totally out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **;** from the query.
Use `$php_var = "SELECT * FROM sen WHERE id=1";`

Comment: -1. `;` doesn't matter. And whole `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` are missing. Read Wouter0100's answer.